# How can I do AppleScript's «event aevtrlgo» in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, applescript, osascript, appleevents

On macOS, the `osascript` command line tool can be used to run AppleScript and JavaScript, both of which have access to the Apple Events API.

For most of the API, the translation is quite straightforward. E.g.

```applescript
tell application "Terminal" to quit
```

translates to:

```js
Application("Terminal").quit()
```

Moreover, in JS there is a `commandsOfClass` function that lists available actions:

```bash
osascript -l JavaScript -e 'Application("Terminal").commandsOfClass()'
# close, count, delete, doScript, duplicate, exists,
# getURL, make, move, open, print, quit, save

osascript -l JavaScript -e 'Application("System Events").commandsOfClass()'
# abortTransaction, attachActionTo, attachedScripts, beginTransaction, cancel, click,
# close, confirm, connect, count, decrement, delete, disconnect, doFolderAction,
# doScript, duplicate, editActionOf, enable, endTransaction, exists, increment,
# keyCode, keyDown, keyUp, keystroke, logOut, make, move, open, perform, pick,
# print, quit, removeActionFrom, restart, save, select, shutDown, sleep, start, stop
```

But AppleScript has some more obscure events, in particular the `aevtrlgo` ("really log out") one:

```applescript
tell application "loginwindow" to «event aevtrlgo»
```

I can't even type the `«»` characters in the Terminal, so here's a copy-paste-able version:

```bash
printf 'tell application "loginwindow" to \xc2\xabevent aevtrlgo\xc2\xbb' | osascript
```

Now, how can I do this `«event aevtrlgo»` in JavaScript?

I've tried things like:

```js
Application("loginwindow").rlgo();
Application("loginwindow").aevtrlgo();
Application("loginwindow").reallyLogOut();
Application("loginwindow").event("rlgo");
Application("loginwindow").event("aevtrlgo");
Application("loginwindow")["«event aevtrlgo»"]();
```

But I always get the exact same response:

```
execution error: Error on line 1: Error: Message not understood. (-1708)
```

Plus `Application("loginwindow").commandsOfClass()` yields an empty list.

Comment: Do you need to do this via command line?

Comment: I ask because I have a workaround that works in Script Editor.

Comment: I can see your deleted answer, and it's an interesting workaround... but no, I can run any code I want, I merely prefer JS and would like to know how to do it "purely".

Comment: doesn't look like there's a 'pure' solution. Looks like a bug in JXA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JXA, like ScriptingBridge before it, is flawed in design and half-baked in implementation, so many operations that work perfectly in AppleScript don't work right/at all (and it's rarely clear why). In this case, JXA lacks public APIs for working with raw four-char codes, which means you're SOOL if JXA/the target app don't provide valid terminology for the AE types/events/etc you want to use.

My standard advice: stick to AppleScript as it's the *only* officially supported option that knows how to speak Apple events right.

Answer (score 0):

This workaround works for me, but only works (as far as I can tell) in Script  Editor:

```
var app = Application.currentApplication();
app.includeStandardAdditions = true;

app.doShellScript('osascript -e "tell application \\"loginwindow\\" to «event aevtrlgo»"');
```

Comment: Now, if you can find a way to get this to work in the command line, I'd sure be curious to find out how